# c# Generic interface casting

Tags: c#, generics, interface

```
public abstract class BusinessObject : ObservableObject, IBusinessObject
public abstract class BusinessModel<T> : IBusinessModel<T> where T : IBusinessObject
public class User : BusinessObject
public class UserModel : BusinessModel<User>
```

Why can i not cast UserModel to IBusinessModel< IBusinessObject>?

Comment: Because there is no variance for classes. Look up covariance and contravariance. This is a duplicate for sure, I hope someone finds a matching question to close this one.

Comment: You don't have a definition of IBusinessModel or IBusinessObject in the question, so who knows?  (But probably because while a `User` is always a `BusinessObject`, a `BusinessObject` may not be a `User` ... and `UserModel` wants a `User`, not a `BusinessObject`)

Comment: There are hundreds of questions on Stack Overflow already asking what you're asking: "why can't I cast my object to something it's not?" See the marked duplicate for one of the earliest examples. It includes some discussion as to why what you think you want to do is actually not safe, and not something your code should be able to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define `IBusinessModel` covariant like this:

```
public interface IBusinessModel<out T>
{
//...
}
```

then it works.

> Covariance 
>   Enables you to use a more derived type than originally specified.

As always, you can refer to the main [reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517(v=vs.110).aspx) for a complete description.

---

Further explanation based on OP's example:
To get on the same page, let's first assume that we have these definitions for the classes and interfaces (as some of the declarations are not presented in the question)

```
abstract class BusinessObject : ObservableObject, IBusinessObject { }
class ObservableObject { }
interface IBusinessObject { }
abstract class BusinessModel<T> : IBusinessModel<T> where T : IBusinessObject { }
interface IBusinessModel<out T> { } //This change should be made as suggested in my answer
class User : BusinessObject { }
class UserModel : BusinessModel<User> { }
```

Now, what happens in the following assignment?

```
IBusinessModel<IBusinessObject> v = new UserModel();
```

1. An implementation of `IBusinessObject`, which is a subclass of `BusinessObject` (i.e. `User`), is used instead of `IBusinessObject`;
2. An implementation of `IBusinessModel` (i.e. `BusinessModel`) is used instead of `IBusinessModel`.

The case 1 doesn't raise any problem because we have already said that we can use any instance of `IBusinessObject` in th definition of `BusinessModel`:

```
abstract class BusinessModel<T> : IBusinessModel<T> where T : IBusinessObject { }
```

The case 2 require `IBusinessModel` to be contravariant (based on the definition quoted earlier):

```
interface IBusinessModel<out T> { } //This change should be made as suggested in my answer
```